# Add values to dict of list in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this kind of dictionary of lists, initially empty:

```
d = dict()
```

Now the use case is to simply add a value to list under a key, which might be a new or an existing key. I think we have to do it like this:

```
if key not in d:
    d[key] = list()
d[key].append(value)
```

This seems awfully tedious and error-prone, needing to write multiple lines (with copy-paste or helper function). Is there a more convenient way?

If there isn't "only one way to do it", and you *know* it, you can also answer that, and maybe suggest alternative ways to accomplish above, even if they aren't necessarily better.

I looked for duplicate, didn't find, but perhaps I just didn't know to use right keywords.

Comment: Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html)?

Comment: There's the `.setdefault` method for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is called a defaultdict, as available in the collections library:

Python2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Python3.7: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```py
Example:
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 11):

`d[key] = d.get(key, []) + [value]`

to explain
`d.get` method returns value under the key `key` and if there is **no** such key, returns optional argument (second), in this case `[]` (empty list)

then you will get the list (empty or not) and than you add list `[value]` to it. this can be also done by `.append(value)` instead of `+ [value]`

having that list, you set it as the new value to that key

e.g.

```
d = {1: [1, 2]}
d[1] = d.get(1, []) + [3]
# d == {1: [1, 2, 3]}

d[17] = d.get(17, []) + [8]
# d == {1: [1, 2, 3], 17: [8]}
```

Comment: Why not just `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl that works, but only for mutable types, it would fail for example `dict(str:int)`

Answer (score 2):

```
d[key] = list() if (key not in d) else d[key].append(value)
```

Uses the ternary operators. And looks somewhat cleaner, however it is still almost identical to your scenario.

I apologize, I wasn't thinking earlier and used standard ternary operators. I changed them to Python ternary operators.

Comment: Python does not have `?:` operator, does it...? There is the `exp1 if cond else exp2` syntax though, you could rewrite the answer using that.

Comment: @hyde that is my bad. I used the wrong ternary operators.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, still... `d[key] = [value] if key not in d else d[key] + [value]` should work and cover both cases correctly.