# Create lists from multiple dicts with same key

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries with data similar to this -

```
Data = [
    {'name': John,
     'age': 10},

    {'name': John,
     'age': 11},

    {'name': John,
     'age': 12},

    {'name': Paul,
     'age': 13},

    {'name': Paul,
     'age': 14},

    {'name': Paul,
     'age': 15},
]
```

I need to loop through this data and build lists such as  -

John

- 10
- 11
- 12

Paul

- 13
- 14
- 15

Whats the best way to approach this?

Comment: Is your list items sorted? (i.e First all `John`s are listed then all `Paul`s etc.)?

Comment: You can get it done using [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336162/4985099)

Comment: In your `dict` the keys are `name` and `role` — is this for real or it's just a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for x in Data:
    (k,) = x.keys() - {'age'}
    res[x[k]].append(x['age'])

print(list(res.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an auxiliary dictionary to build the list:

```
the_lists = {}

for d in data:
    if d['name'] in the_lists:
         the_lists['name'].append(d['age'])
    else:
       the_lists[d['name']] = [d['age']]
```

`the_lists` is the dictionary that will contain all the ages for each name.
Also, consider using `snake_case` for variable names in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for item in Data:
  key = item.get("name") or item.get("role")
  result[key].append(item.get("age"))

print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{'Paul': [13, 14, 15], 'John': [10, 11, 12]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newdict = {}

for d in Data:
    k, v = d
    print(k, v)
    if d[k] in newdict:
         newdict[d[k]].append(d['age'])
    else:
       newdict[d[k]] = [d['age']]

print(newdict)

>>> {'John': [10, 11, 12], 'Paul': [13, 14, 15]}
```